# Problem with decimals when setting price for ico

Tags: contract-development

```
 /// @notice Constructor of the contract
function startToken() {
    IcoIsRunning = true;
    minimalGoalReached = false;
    icoIsClosed = false;
    tokenBalanceOf[this] += _totalSupply;
    allowed[this][owner] = _totalSupply;
    currentTokenPrice = 1;  // CURRENT price of 1 Token
    ICOprice = 1;               // ICO price
    updatePrices();
}
```

How do I set this if I want an exchange rate of 1 token for 0.001 ETH?
On this code, it's 1 ETH per 1 token(ICOprice)
I tried many different ways with no success.

Comment: You might need to use a fixed-point math library. See [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity).

Answer (score 0):

All the calculations in solidity are done using wei. When you write `1 ether`, it gets used as `1e18`, which is 1 followed by 18 zeros.

So your variables would have following effect:

```
IcoPrice = 1000 * 1e18;
buyBackPrice = 1000 * 9e17;
```

Its not clear where you want to *set* this, I hope having an idea of what it means will enable you to set this as per your requirement.

Comment: It's a token sale contract where the user can buy 1 token at 0.001 ether, and he can send the tocken back but the price will be reduced by 10%. I am not able to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set 1 token per 0.001, meaning it's 1000 token per 1 ETH, set it this way:

```
uint256 public rate = 1000;
```

Then calculating the rate based on msg.value:

```
amountToGive = rate.mul(msg.value); // if user send 1 ETH it will give 1000 tokens.
```

Understand that here, msg.value is in WEI (so if I send 1 ETH, msg.value = 1000000000000000000 WEI,  1000000000000000000 * 1000 = 1×10²¹ OR 1000000000000000000000 WEI which is 1000 ETH/token

So this solution will work if your token have 18 decimals.

For 10% rate, it would be 900 tokens per ETH so:

```
uint256 public rate = 900;
amountToGive = rate.mul(msg.value); // if user send 1 ETH it will give 900 tokens.
```

Notice this whole code use [SafeMath Library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. It returns an error even if I included  SafeMath.

Comment: If you could tell me the error or share me somewhere as pastbin the full script so O can debug the issue, I will gladly do :)

Comment: For some reason I am not able to set the amount of tokens x eth, but only the amount of eth x tokens. I need to set 0.001 eth, and I can't find the way to set this decimal number. I tried buyPrice= 1/1000; but it returns an error: TypeError: Type rational_const 1 / 1000 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. Try converting to type ufixed8x3 or use an explicit conversion.

Comment: You cannot use decimals nor ufixed value for now. Please read doc and use google

Comment: I told you I could understand better with code. Solution I propose fully working for me.

Comment: I updated the code. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Calculation I put is amount of token for ONE ETH :)Do the math! Rate value * by amount of eth send.